# Identify drag event jquery

Tags: jquery

I have implemented file upload functionality using uploadifive library. In there I can give a div for drag and drop. So, now I want to highlight that div when drag event get fired. 
There are enough examples for drag object such as divs withing the page and identify their drag event. But I couldn't find a solution for drag event with file dragging.

```
 document.addEventListener('dragover', function (e) {
        console.log('drag over');
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
 }, false);
```

Comment: Could you please post a reproducible test case / sample code so that we could tell you exactly what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a `dragover` event. You need to bind the event to `body` or `document` and then whenever you detect the `dragover` , do whatever you need to do (highlighting the drop area).

sample

```
/* events fired on the drop targets */
document.addEventListener("dragover", function( event ) {
    // prevent default to allow drop
    event.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Do not forget the `preventDefault()`. Also not that this fires on every mouse move, so adding heavy computation to this is not advisable.

You can read more info [over here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/dragover)